# reordering control in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am developing a game in which I am using a `UITableView` which has custom cell (`UItableViewCell` subclass).

**In editing mode:**
Only the reordering control of the `UITableView` should show.

Right now I am getting the delete and the reordering control.

**How to get only reordering control while editing ?**

Answer (score 65):

I know this answer might be late, but I'm putting it just for people who still need it.
Just implement the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{

}
```

Comment: still nothing - I have 2 kinds of UITableViewCell in one UITableView. Printing data works smoothly, but in no way I can manage to show rearranging control :/

Answer (score 4):

thanks a lot oxigen it worked ....
i was writing this in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (!cell) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     }

     cell.showsReorderControl = YES; // to show reordering control

    return cell;
}
```

but i dint write the method which you have given

Thanks a tons

Answer (score 4):

You should use this method for hiding delete button.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5.0

If you want to disable all other editing options for your tableView's cells except the one that allows you to reorder them then just implement those methods from UITableViewDelegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    true
}

// Removes the ability to delete current cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 tableView.showsReorderControl = YES; // to show reordering control
```

To dissmiss delete control, in your UITableViewDelegate add

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```