# Reorder UITableView and hide reorder control

Tags: ios, uitableview

My question is like this: [Reordering UITableView without reorder control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624730/reordering-uitableview-without-reorder-control), I use these methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{

}
```

And

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES];

......

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ItemTableViewCell *cell = (ItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // ...
    cell.showsReorderControl = NO;
    return cell;
}
```

References: [reordering control in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361820/reordering-control-in-uitableview)

The result is that **the table can be reordered, but the reorder control never hide**. So I wonder if I am wrong, or if anybody can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check This URL:[Reordering a UITableViewCell from any Touch point](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point).This might be helpful to you

Comment: Can I suggest trying [BVReorderTableView](https://github.com/bvogelzang/BVReorderTableView)? Instead of hacking UITableView cell subviews it offers a bit cleaner solution.

Comment: Dead link. Should post a proper answer to avoid this.