# UITableView reordering cells in UIViewController - reorder control not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to have UITableView with 2 classes of UITableViewCell (section 0 with one row, section 1 with [self.dataArray count] rows).

I tried these links:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html

[reordering control in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361820/reordering-control-in-uitableview)
[Reorder control isn't displayed on table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769418/reorder-control-isnt-displayed-on-table-view)

I've added:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{   

    // Get the object we are going to move
    Task *task = [[Task alloc] init];
    task = [self.taskArray  objectAtIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
    
    // We will delete and move it to another location so well have to retain it
    //[task retain];
    
    // Remove it an move it to other place
    [self.taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row]];
    [self.taskArray insertObject:task atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
}


     // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
     - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
         if (indexPath.section == 1) {
             return YES;
         }
         return YES;
     }
```

And I did add for every UITableViewCell class:

```
cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
```

but still no luck, no reaorderControl is showing... anybody? This is quite urgent and annoying to have so many tutorials, but not working for me.

#### EDIT:

I changed a bit topic to include fact, that I was using UIViewController not UITableViewController.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To implement row reordering in a `UITableView`, you need to implement `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`, You might also want to implement `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`.

And the most important, the table view must be in edit mode for the reorder controls to appear.

Comment: I've added to my navigationItem.rightbuttons `[self editButtonItem];` but pressed didn't initiate drag controller to appear - any idea? I don't want to have table set all the time to edit mode

Comment: I mean, beside constructing custom button with atached method - is there a proper or better way to achieve that?

Comment: Adding `[self editButtonItem]` is good assuming you are using a `UITableViewController` and not a `UIViewController`. Are you overriding the `setEditing:animated:` method by any chance? If you are, make sure you call `[super setEditing:editing animated:animated]'`.

Comment: thanks, you saved my life :) it looks like every one here on SO was using UITableViewController, so they didn't add this little detail :)

Comment: You can still use `[self editButtonItem]` in a `UIViewController`. You just need to make sure that you override `setEditing:animated:` to include a call to `[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated]`.

Comment: Like he said: if you are not using a UITableViewController, you must manually call the self.tableView.setEditing() method inside the self.setEditing() method. (Note same method name for both controller and view!)

Comment: This is the key ingredient I was missing: `the table view must be in edit mode for the reorder controls to appear`

Answer (score 0):

try this  . . .this will handle arranging and updating of cell in case of simple tableview in editing mode

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
     [tableData insertObject: [tableData objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row] atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
     [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row + 1)];
}
```